# ECHO is off error while executing batch file

Tags: batch-file

Executing batch file gives ECHO is off.

The batch file code is present below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET a = Hello 
SET b = World 
SET /A d = 50 
SET c = %a% and %b% %d%
echo %c%

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Try `echo.%c%`.

Comment: Spaces on the right side of the equal sign are included in the value of the variable, BUT the spaces on the left side of the equal sign are included in the variable name. You don't have `a`, `b` and `c` variables, you have `a `, `b ` and `c ` variables (with an additional space)

Comment: MC ND CAn you help me out with this code please.@echo off
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

     set pathToJava= **Provide your Response: 

     IF /I "%pathToJava%" == "Y"(
     @echo found
    )

    endlocal
    pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MC ND wrote, you have to get rid of spaces before and behind the equality sign. It should be `SET a=Hello` and not `SET a = Hello` and so on. This code works as expected:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET a=Hello 
SET b=World 
SET /A d=50 
SET c=%a% and %b% %d%
echo %c%

endlocal
pause
```

Further, the lines `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` are useless in your code as you never use the delayed expansion (e.g. `!a!` instead of `%a%`). Your code is still correct as there is doesn't need delayed expansion.

If you have further questions, please post them as such. Don't expand this post on other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your two, *altered* codes:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "a=Hello"
SET "b=World"
SET/A "d=50"
SET "c=%a% and %b% %d%"
ECHO %c%

ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

Please check and try them, then read up on the individual commands to learn from your errors.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET/P "pathToJava= **Provide your Response: "
IF /I "%pathToJava%"=="Y" ECHO found
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```